# How can I redirect to an action in .Net Core after making an Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a script that makes an ajax call to an action in the controller and save some records.

The whole process is working fine but my little issue is to redirect to another page after saving records successfully.

With my code below, the records were added successfully with an alert indicating as it is described in the code "`msg + "Courses were Registered"`". Rather than doing that I want it to redirect to an action.

Javascript code:

```
 <input type="submit" value="Register Courses" id="register" class="btn btn-rose" />
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $("#register").click(function () {
                   var items = [];
               $('input:checkbox.checkBox').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                        var item = {};
                        item.CourseID = $(this).val();
                        item.CourseCode = $(this).parent().next().html();
                        item.CourseName = $(this).parent().next().next().html();
                        item.Units = $(this).parent().next().next().next().html();
                        items.push(item);
                    }
                    });

                    var options = {};
                    options.url = "/Course/SaveCourse";
                    options.type = "POST";
                    options.dataType = "json";
                    options.data = JSON.stringify(items);
                    options.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8;";
                    options.success = function (msg) {
                        alert(msg + " Courses were Registered");
                    };
                    options.error = function () {
                        alert("Error while Registering Courses");
                    };
                    $.ajax(options);
                });

            });

        </script>
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SaveCourse([FromBody]List<CourseRegModel> courseIDs)
        {

            var user = HttpContext.Session.GetString("currentUser");
            if (user == null)
            {
              return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            ViewBag.student = user;
            var pendingPayment = (from row in _context.BursaryTransactions where row.MatricNo == user && row.ResponseCode == "021" select row).Count();
            if (pendingPayment > 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("PaymentSummary", "Student");
            }
            var student = _context.StStudentInfo.Include(m =>m.AdmInstProgramme.AdmInstDepartment).Include(m =>m.AdmInstClassLevels).FirstOrDefault(m => m.MatricNo == user);
            var session = _context.AdmInstProgrammeTypeSession.Include(m => m.AdmInstSemesters).Include(m => m.AdmInstSessions).Include(m => m.AdmInstProgramType).Where(m => m.IsActive == true).FirstOrDefault(m => m.ProgramTypeId == student.ProgrammeTypeId);
            foreach (CourseRegModel courseID in courseIDs)
            {
                courseID.Level = student.AdmInstClassLevels.ClassLevel;
                courseID.Semester = session.AdmInstSemesters.Semester;
                courseID.Session = session.AdmInstSessions.SessionName;
                courseID.Department = student.AdmInstProgramme.AdmInstDepartment.Department;
                _context.CourseRegModel.Add(courseID);

            }
            int courses = _context.SaveChanges();

            return Json(courses);
        }
```

Objective is to `return RedirectToAction("MyCourses","Courses");` after `SaveChanges();`

Comment: You want to redirect to another page, so don't use ajax.

Comment: The *only* point of AJAX is to issue requests to the server without causing the page to change. If your goal is to redirect, then there's no point in using AJAX. Just do a standard form post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to another action method why would you use AJAX? But I think you can work around that by performing the redirect in the client side AJAX after it is successfully receive a response you use JavaScript to do the redirect

Answer (score 0):

You can simply redirect your page inside ajax's success handler,

```
options.success = function (msg) {
    window.localtion.href = "/Courses/MyCourses";
    // or window.location.href = '@url.Action("MyCourses","Courses")';
};
```